# Simplest way to run a background task

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous

I have the following code which takes a couple seconds to run and I want it to run in a background thread, so it doesn't interrupt the normal output data of the function. Here's the current code I have which runs synchronously:

```
t0 = time.time()
self.save(entity_id=4)
t1 = time.time
# this should take no time -- now it takes about 3s, and can be put in a separate thread.
```

How would I put this method in a background thread? For example:

```
thread = threading.Thread(self.save(entity)id=d)
thread.start()
```

I know the above doesn't work: but what would be the suggested way to do something similar? I am using python3

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import threading
t0 = time.time()
t = threading.Thread(target=self.save, args=(4,))
t.start()
print time.time() - t0
```